# Random microphone crackles

Tags: windows-7, audio, skype, microphone, teamspeak

I have recently experienced some problems with my microphone.

When I play in a game, my microphone randomly starts crackling. As far as I know this happens cross-platform (Skype, TS), and haven't experienced it happening out of a game as of yet.

The microphone is plugged directly to the motherboard, as the front panel doesn't work, therefore can't try using another jack plug? (called).

Have tried talking to a friend, suggesting it could be my upstream bandwidth, although I currently have 30/30, and nowhere near use it all.

If any other information is needed, I'd like you to tell how and where to find that, as I don't really know that, sorry.

Comment: Yes, on the back side of the computer there are plugs directly to the motherboard.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think I can, although the problem only happens while in a game, thus meaning it might be something else than the microphone itself, or what?

Comment: Its most likely your connection not your mic hardware. Cabling and mic faults would cause buzzing or crackling, stuttering is packets going missing or being delayed too much.

Comment: Guess crackling would be the correct word to use to describe my problem, sorry for using stuttering, wasn't sure how to say it in english. I have no problems whatsoever with my internet connection, and microphone hasn't taken any hits or the like. Is it possible at all that it's a software issue?

Comment: Can you have one of your friends record the other end? Might make it easier to diagnose. Your connection to the game w/e can be fine but still have a junk link to the VOIP server.

Comment: I found out that it happens without the game, and that it could be my wire being the problem. Here's the crackling sound. https://www.dropbox.com/s/dvfb3avojptuea2/Crackling%20sound.wma?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the issue is with mic,  cable or jack.

You can't use another jack so test another mic. If this isn't conclusive then buy a cheap Audio card to test it

Lastly, ensure this sounds issue exists only when the mic is plugged in. I have had issues similar to only later realise there was an on board external microphone which was always on

Answer (score 0):

Random "noise" sounding crackling (like what we used to experience on analog telephone lines during wet weather) is due to poor connections on the analog side of the system -- internal to the microphone or at the plug and jack connections.  Breaking up that sounds like randomly inserted blank time or garbling without added noise is on the digital side, and will be due to packet loss, excessive latency, or packets arriving too far out of order for the VOIP software to reconstruct.